# Identificar elementos repetidos em lista com Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

A lista que fiz deveria ler os valores repetidos de uma lista e mostrar suas posições, porém não funcionou corretamente

```
lista = []

listaRepetido = True
for i in range(4):
    lista.append(int(input("Numero: ")))

for i in lista:
    for j in range(2,i):
        if ((i == j) == 0):
            listaRepetido = False
            break

    if listaRepetido:
            posicao = lista.index(i)
            print("Numero %i na %i° posiçaõ" % (i, posicao + 2))
    listaRepetido = True
```

Comment: `if ((i == j) == 0):`, o que isso deveria fazer?

Comment: comparar o elemento de i com o elemento de j, e depois verificar se é igual a zero

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Utilizando `collections.defaultdict` fica bem mais simples este cálculo:

```
from collections import defaultdict

# Define a lista de volares:
lista = [3, 2, 4, 7, 3, 8, 2, 3, 8, 1]

# Define o objeto que armazenará os índices de cada elemento:
keys = defaultdict(list);

# Percorre todos os elementos da lista:
for key, value in enumerate(lista):

    # Adiciona o índice do valor na lista de índices:
    keys[value].append(key)

# Exibe o resultado:
for value in keys:
    if len(keys[value]) > 1:
        print(value, keys[value])
```

O resultado exibido é:

```
2 [1, 6] 
3 [0, 4, 7] 
8 [5, 8]
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/URWlhk).

Comment: no caso vc exibiu todos os valores, mas preciso mostrar so os repetidos, q nessa sua lista seria os valores 3, 2, 8.

Comment: @JuniorSilva verdade, corrigido já.

Comment: Show, mano!! valeu mesmo :)

Answer (score 2):

Outra forma interessante é utilizando o método `Counter` da biblioteca **[collections](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3.8/library/collections.html)**. Neste caso, o código ficaria:

```
from collections import Counter

lista = list(map(int, input('Digite os valores: ').split()))
c = Counter(lista)

for numero, repeticoes in c.items():
    if repeticoes > 1:
        result = [indice for indice, item in enumerate(lista) if item == numero]
        print(f'O número "{numero}" se repete nos índices {result}.')
```

Observe que quando executamos este código recebemos a seguinte mensagem: `Digite os valores:` . Neste momento devemos digitar **todos** os valores, na **mesma linha**, **separados** por um só espaço e pressionar `Enter`.

**OBS:** Com este código você poderá inserir quantos números desejares em sua lista.

Neste momento o bloco **for** percorrerá o objeto `c.items()` e se o número de **repetições** de um determinado **numero** for maior que **1**, será montada a lista **result**. Esta lista será formada por List Comprehensions e, posteriormente será exibido o resultado composto pelo número que possui mais de 1 ocorrência e os respectivos índices de suas ocorrências.

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma que encontrei foi essa:

```
   for i, elemento in enumerate(lista):
        if elemento in lista[i+1:]:
            print(f'Elemento repetido: {elemento}')
```

O if verifica se o elemento está em alguma posição após ele mesmo, se sim, é um número repetido.