# Identificar strings repetidos em uma lista

Tags: python

Estou fazendo um programa onde um usuário vai adicionar historias, ele vai adicionar o tema, o titulo e o corpo da história, e eu coloquei tudo isso em dicionarios e adicionei eles em uma lista.

```
 historias = [{'tema':'Princesas', 'titulo':'A princesa', 'A princesa':'TextoAPrincesa'},
             {'tema':'Super Herois', 'titulo':'Iron Man 2', 'Iron Man 2':'TextoIronMan'},
             {'tema':'Princesas', 'titulo':'A princesinha', 'A princesinha':'TextoAprincesinha'}]
```

Então o meu problema é o seguinte, eu gostaria de identificar quando o tema tem valores iguais, como por exemplo no dicionário que existe dois temas com o mesmo valor "Princesas", então eu pensei em uma solução de adicionar os nomes dos temas em uma lista e descobrir se algum valor se repete.

```
lista = []
for i in range(len(historias)):
    lista.append(historias[i]['tema'])
print(lista)`
```

Mas eu não estou conseguindo identificar se existe valores repetidos nesta lista, procurei e apenas achei soluções para descobrir inteiros repetidos e não strings. Alguém poderia ajudar?

Comment: Relacionada? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/216413/identificar-elementos-repetidos-em-lista-com-python?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que aconselho é que antes de você usar o método `append()`, primeiro verificar se a o tema já está na lista com o operador `in`, que retorna `True` caso esteja, e `False`, caso não esteja.

Como a condição pra adicionar o tema na lista é não estar presente, é só usar o operador `not`, pra inverter o resultado da condição.

```py
lista = list()

for i in range(len(historias)):
    if not historias[i]['tema'] in lista:
        lista.append(historias[i]['tema'])
```

Caso a ordem dos elementos não importe, você pode usar um `set` e o metodo `add()`, pois ele não permite elementos repetidos. Ficando o código assim:

```py
lista = set()

for i in range(len(historias)):
        lista.add(historias[i]['tema'])
```