# Como saber se em uma lista possui vários valores iguais?

Tags: python

Eu estou querendo fazer uma função que retorne os elementos iguais de uma lista.

```
cartas_jogador_a = ['4', '7', '10', '8', '1', '10']
```

Eu queria obter somente  os valores '10', '10' em uma outra lista, já tentei usar o laço while e for mas não obtive resultado.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/216413/identificar-elementos-repetidos-em-lista-com-python pode te ajudar :)

Answer (score -2):

Você pode usar um for para comparar todos os elementos da lista com o valor que você procura.

```
cartas_jogador = [1,2,8,4,5,6,7,8]
for carta in cartas_jogador:
    valor_objetivo = 8
    if carta == valor_objetivo:
       outra_lista.append(carta)
```